# sfdx force:source:deploy fails with UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION

Tags: salesforcedx, exception, salesforcedx-cli

Yesterday it worked, but when I deploy my DX projects to my Sandbox using

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p ./force-app  -l RunLocalTests -u TargetOrg -w 15
```

it fails with:

```
=== Component Failures [1]
TYPE   FILE                             NAME  PROBLEM
─────  ───────────────────────────────  ────  ─────────────────
Error  sdx_sourceDeploy_1561452085648/        UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION


PROJECT PATH  ERROR
────────────  ───────────────────────
N/A           UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION (0:0)
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Deploy failed.
```

Is there a way to get more info, why this happened? And what is this `sdx_sourceDeploy_1561452085648` file? Couldn't find it locally.

Checking the Deploy status in the Target Org also didn't reveal more:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to watch the error in the target org -> Setup -> Deployment Status -> View Errors? I have noticed during last 2 months, that this error has more details in there.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova your comment is more suited as an answer :)